# Authorize user from one point to all page in asp.net MVC5

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

```
[Authorize(Users = "example@gmail.com")]
```

I don't want to add this line in every controller. Instead I want to authorize user to every page from a single point. What should I do?

Help me! Even reference is considered if you know.

Comment: You can add an event 'Application_AuthenticateRequest' in global.asax. This method will be called on every request.

For Example:
Protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//Your authentication\authorization logic.
}